# Creating a JSON String from a Swift object in Xcode 7+

Tags: swift2

I have the following class that I need to convert into a JSON String using Xcode 7 and above. In the previous version of Xcode there was a `JSONSerelization.toJson(AnyObject)` function available, however does not appear in Xcode7 .

I need to convert the following class :

```
struct ContactInfo
{
    var contactDeviceType: String
    var contactNumber: String
}

class Tradesmen
{
    var type:String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var companyName: String = ""
    var contacts: [ContactInfo] = []

init(type:String, name:String, companyName:String, contacts [ContactInfo])
    {
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.companyName = companyName
        self.contacts = contacts
    }
```

I Have set up my test data as follows

```
contactType =
        [
           ContactInfo(contactDeviceType: "Home", contactNumber: "(604) 555-1111"),
           ContactInfo(contactDeviceType: "Cell", contactNumber: "(604) 555-2222"),
           ContactInfo(contactDeviceType: "Work", contactNumber: "(604) 555-3333")
        ]




var tradesmen = Tradesmen(type: "Plumber", name: "Jim Jones", companyName: "Jim Jones Plumbing", contacts: contactType)
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is any direct way, even in previous Xcode. You will need to write your own implementation. Something like below:

```
protocol JSONRepresenatble {
    static func jsonArray(array : [Self]) -> String
    var jsonRepresentation : String {get}
}

extension JSONRepresenatble {
    static func jsonArray(array : [Self]) -> String {
        return "[" + array.map {$0.jsonRepresentation}.joinWithSeparator(",") + "]"
    }
}
```

And then implement JSONRepresentable in your modals like below:

```
struct ContactInfo: JSONRepresenatble {
    var contactDeviceType: String
    var contactNumber: String
    var jsonRepresentation: String {
        return "{\"contactDeviceType\": \"\(contactDeviceType)\", \"contactNumber\": \"\(contactNumber)\"}"
    }
}

struct Tradesmen: JSONRepresenatble {
    var type:String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var companyName: String = ""
    var contacts: [ContactInfo] = []
    var jsonRepresentation: String {
        return "{\"type\": \"\(type)\", \"name\": \"\(name)\", \"companyName\": \"\(companyName)\", \"contacts\": \(ContactInfo.jsonArray(contacts))}"
    }
    init(type:String, name:String, companyName:String, contacts: [ContactInfo]) {
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.companyName = companyName
        self.contacts = contacts
    }
}
```